# why PHP stack (that i build) didnt work?

Tags: php, stack

i try to build stack in PHP, but its didnt work. why?

**this is the problem that i see:**

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for object::object(), called in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\tb\index.php on line 152 and defined in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\tb\index.php on line 126

Notice: Undefined variable: txt in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\tb\index.php on line 127

Fatal error: Call to undefined function back() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\tb\index.php on line 146
```

**this is the code:** *(i wrote in the code the lines of the problem with // )*

```
class object {
    private $obj;
    private $next = null;
    private $back = null;

    public function object($txt) {     // line 126
        $this->obj = $txt;     // line 127
    }
    public function back($back) {
        $this->back = $back;
    }
    public function next($next) {
        $this->next = $next;
    }
}

class stack2 extends object  {
    private $arr;
    private $head = -1;
    private $tail = 0;

    public function push($txt) {
        $this->head++;
        $arr[$this->head] = new object($txt);  
        if ($this->head-1 >= $this->tail) {  
            $arr[$this->head].back($this->head-1);     // line 146 
            $arr[$this->head-1].next($this->head); 
        }
    }
}

$s = new stack2();   // line 152
$s->push(11111);
$s->push(22222);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `object` constructor defines one argument `$txt` to instanciate the class. In your class `stack2` which inherts from `object` you must also write a constructor which calls its parent constructor with the needed parameter.

```
class stack2 extends object {
  public function __construct() {
    $txt = 'your text here';

    parent::object($txt);
  }
}
```

And I would use the magic method `__construct` instead of a method with the same name as the class. Because if you refactor classes name you also have to refactor your constructor functions name.

Your second error is that you call a method of an object with a `.` instead of `->`. So the correct line would be:

```
$arr[$this->head]->back($this->head-1);
```

Than you want propably use the property `$arr` of your `stack` class so you have to use `$this->arr` instead of simply `$arr` in the example line above.

Comment: thanks! its solve the first problem. but i still have the third problem (in line 146). if i 'push' just 1 object, everythig works good. but if i try to 'push' more then that, its show me the eror.

Comment: You call methods of objects with `->` and not with a `.` in PHP.